# Download tgz file to colab

Tags: python, dataset, google-colaboratory

I want to use the IAM handwriting dataset from [this](https://fki.tic.heia-fr.ch/databases/download-the-iam-handwriting-database) link on colab.

However, I'm unable to download any of the tgz files on the page from their links. I've tried `!wget` as well as `tf.keras.utils.get_file` but none of them give me the intended result. Instead of the tgz file, they return the html webp.

Do you know how to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: Very naive comment, but for me when I click on the links, they ask for login and password. So possibly you can look into that.

Comment: @Suvo I don't think that's the problem. After accidentally downloading the html of the page to colab, pressing the link still gave me the actual file.